# jQuery exception for class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, checkbox

I have a table with checkboxes. The header checkbox can select/deselect all. I also have an image (#delAllPort) that deletes the checked rows from the table. I need to make an expection for the checkbox (and it's corresponding row) that checks all so that the header in never deleted. I used .not() with the class, but it doesn't seem to be working. Thanks in advance. Here's my jQuery:

```
$('#delAllPort').click(function(){
  $('tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)').not('.selAllChksInGroup').each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

...and here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/8kDRe/

Comment: Please post the HTML you're applying this to, and if possible create a jsFiddle.

Comment: with "it doesn't seem to be working" you mean it is deleting all rows including the header row?

Comment: It deletes all rows and won't take the exception.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8kDRe/1/

Comment: @Explosion Pills: Perfect! I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr:has(input:checkbox:checked:not(.selAllChksInGroup))').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)').not('.selAllChksInGroup')
```

to

```
$('tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)').not('tr:has(input.selAllChksInGroup)')
```

because your selector is select TR and not INPUT.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class `selAllChksInGroup` to the tr instead of the td: http://jsfiddle.net/8kDRe/3/

Answer (score 0):

Surround the "header" with `<thead>` and the rest of the rows with `<tbody>`.  Then, just select rows in `<tbody>` to delete:

```
$('tbody tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8kDRe/4/